# Cual es la diferencia entre llamar a una funcion con/sin parentesis en Python?

Tags: python

- Presentare mi duda a traves del siguiente codigo...

```
>>> def saludo():
...   print('Hola Mundo :-) ');
... 
>>> saludo
<function saludo at 0x000001EA97507F70>
>>> saludo()
Hola Mundo :-)
```

-La pregunta seria la siguiente: ¿Que quiere decir el valor que retorna la funcion cuando se le llama sin parentesis?

Answer (score 2):

Una función es un objeto de tipo *callable*. El nombre de la función no es más que un símbolo para referirse a ese objeto.

Cuando haces:

```
def saludo():
   print('Hola Mundo :-) ');
```

Ocurren dos cosas:

1. Python crea un objeto de tipo `function` que contiene el código de esa función (y algo más de meta-información acerca de la misma, como por ejemplo su *signature*, que consiste en los nombres y valores por defecto de sus parámetros, o también su *docstring*, que es la documentación de la función, que se toma de la primera línea después del `def`, si esa línea es una cadena.
2. Python crea el símbolo `saludo` que "apunta" al objeto funcion creado en el paso 1.

Ese símbolo no es diferente a cualquier otra variable python, por lo que podemos asignárselo a otra variable, como por ejemplo `x = saludo`. En este caso tendremos que el objeto `function` creado en el paso 1, tiene ahora dos referencias (dos nombres por así decir), `saludo` y `x`.

Para ejecutar una función se usan los paréntesis tras el nombre, como en `saludo()`. Cuando aparecen esos paréntesis el intérprete crea un marco de pila para la función, prepara los parámetros si los hubiera, y salta a la primera instrucción del código (que está en el objeto `function`  al que apunta el símbolo `saludo`).

También significa que puedes pasar una función como parámetro:

```
def ejecutor(f):
   f()

ejecutor(saludo)
```

En este caso el parámetro `f` de `ejecutor()` apunta al objeto `function` señalado por el símbolo `saludo`. Es decir, `f` y  `saludo` se refieren al mismo objeto `function`. Así que cuando luego se hace `f()`, se está ejecutando esa función.

También es posible que una función retorne otra. Por ejemplo:

```
def ejemplo_raro(x):
   def saludo2():
      return f"Hola {x}"
   return saludo2

f = ejemplo_raro("user")
f()
```

Si sigues con cuidado el ejemplo, verás que la línea que hace `f=...` está asignando a la variable `f` el resultado devuelto por la invocación de `ejemplo_raro()`. Y lo que esa función retorna es `saludo2`, que es una función definida internamente. Esta función, por ser interna, no sería visible desde fuera, pero ya que ha sido retornado el símbolo `saludo2`, se está retornando el objeto `function` que se creó internamente dentro de `ejemplo_raro()`.

Así que `f` apunta a un objeto `function` por lo que podemos llamarlo con `f()` y estaremos llamando a la función interna `saludo2()`, que no recibe parámetros. ¡Sin embargo se imprime "Hola user", porque la función interna aún tiene acceso al parámetro `x` de la función externa! Es lo que se llama una *closure* y es posible porque el objeto `function` correspondiente al código de `saludo2()`, contiene además del código, el *docstring*, etc... un diccionario de variables locales y parámtros de `ejemplo_raro()`.

Este asunto de los closures es un poco avanzado, pero es la clave para poder crear por ejemplo decoradores.

### La llamada

Cuando tras un símbolo pones paréntesis como en `saludo()`, en realidad lo que ocurre es que Python invocará `saludo.__call__()` Es ese método especial (o mágico) el que hace que ese objeto sea *callable*.

Por tanto las funciones no son el único objeto *callable*. Cualquiera que implemente un método llamado `__call__()` se puede invocar también como si fuera una función. Por ejemplo:

```
>>> class Llamable:
...    def __init__(self, dato):
...       self.dato = dato
...
...    def __call__(self, parametro):
...       return f"parametro={parametro}, dato={self.dato}"

>>> f = Llamable("mundo")
>>> f("hola")
'parametro=hola, dato=mundo'
```

Answer (score 1):

Cuando colocas el nombre de una función con paréntesis, la función es invocada y su código es ejecutado, en ese caso **si estás llamando a la función**.

Cuando haces referencia a una función sin paréntesis, python te devuelve la dirección en memoria de dicha función, lo que en adelante llamaré una *referencia a la función*. En este caso **no estás llamando a la función**, pues su código no es ejecutado.

Puedes almacenar esta referencia en memoria para ejecutar más adelante la función. De esta manera, puedes tener una variable que sea *ejecutable*.

Mira este ejemplo:

```
def default():
    print("función default")
    
def uno():
    print("función uno")
    
def dos():
    print("función dos")
    
referencia = None
seleccion = input("¿uno o dos? ")
if seleccion.lower() == "uno":
    referencia = uno
elif seleccion.lower() == "dos":
    referencia = dos
else:
    referencia = default
    
print("la selección es:")
referencia();
```

Al terminar el `if` la variable `referencia` va a tener almacenada una u otra función, ninguna de las tres se ha invocado (de otra manera, verías la impresión).

La función cuya referencia hemos almacenado, es ejecutada en la línea:

```
referencia()
```

Esto ejecutará `uno()`, `dos()` o `default()` según lo que haya ingresado el usuario.

No está de más decir que esta característica es de gran utilidad.

Answer (score 0):

En python TODO es un objeto, así que cuando imprimes directamente el objeto, en este caso una función sin ejecutar, Python devuelve la representación en memoria del mismo. Al ponerle los paréntesis entonces se ejecuta.

```
>>> type(saludo)
<class 'function'>
```

La referencia puede formar parte del código, incluso podrías asignársela a otra variable:

```
>>> a = saludo
>>> a()
Hola mundo :-)
>>> b = [a, saludo]
>>> b[0]() 
Hola mundo :-)
>>> b[1]()
Hola mundo :-)
```

Y sucede con muchos objetos de Python, en este caso, [map()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) devuelve un iterador:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y = map(lambda z: z*2, x)
>>> y
<map object at 0x000001E359AEDEE0>
>>> type(y)
<class 'map'>
>>> list(y)
[2, 4, 6]
```