# ¿Qué significa <function my_Function at 0x0000023694587F70> en listas de Python? #Python #List

Tags: python, lista, variables

Alguien podría recomendarme algun tipo de documentacion en inglés o español para este problema

```
def my_Function(myparameter) :   
    myparameter.append('hello')

various_values = [1, 2, 3]
my_Function(various_values)
print(my_Function)
```

---

```
# RESULT =

<function my_Function at 0x0000023694587F70>
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que estabas intentando? Lo que te sale no es ningún error. Cuando llamas a `my_Function()`, pasándole una lista, lo que hará la función es alterar esa lista. Imagino que a continuación querías imprimir el resultado, pero en lugar de `various_values` estás imprimiendo `my_Function` que es un objeto de tipo función, y que es justamente lo que te sale como resultado (los objetos-función son representados así al tratar de imprimirlos). Quizás te interese [esta otra pregunta relacionada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/445670/7123)

Comment: Tienes razón era más que un problema de sintaxis, un problema de la forma lògica en como escribí el programa en ese momento, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

El resultado te está indicando que `my_Function` es una función (y que está en la dirección de memoria `0x0000023694587F70`).

Para llamar a la función no te olvides de incluir `()` después del nombre de la función.

Por tanto, para que funcione como tú quieres, tienes que cambiar `print(my_Function)` por `print(my_Function())`. De esta última manera, imprimes lo que devuelva la llamada a la función: `my_Function()`

De todas formas, no va a imprimir nada a menos que modifiques la función para que devuelva algún valor, por ejemplo:

```
def add(myparameter) :   
    myparameter.append('hello')

def my_Function():
    return various_values

various_values = [1, 2, 3]
add(various_values)
print(my_Function())
```

El resultado es:

```
[1, 2, 3, 'hello']
```

Comment: Genial! Ya pude solucionar con sus comentarios, ya entendi que intentaba imprimir era la función más no el valor que cambió